JXTable Filter. How to filter across all columns?
I am using JXTable and applying filter to it.
  public void filterOnKeyPress(JTextField field) {
    field.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
            String searchText = field.getText().toUpperCase();
            int column = 2;
            if(searchText.isEmpty()){
                table.setFilters(null);
            }else{
                table.setFilters(new FilterPipeline(new PatternFilter(searchText, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE, column)));
            }
        }
    });
}

It is working fine on selected column. How can I make it work across all columns?
